# SQL server transaction issue using perl DBI

Tags: sql, sql-server, perl, transactions, dbi

I have the below code block with a `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` statement inside a **`BEGIN TRAN`**  and **`END TRAN`** block.

Now we all know that this operation is atomic. But i am seeing otherwise. the insert fails due to a unique constraint violation , but still the UPDATE happens. When I execute the same piece in SQL server directly , i can see that the operation is perfectly atomic. Is there anything on the **PERL DBI** front which is overriding the `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT TRAN`. Any Pointers ?

> ```
> $dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
> $dbh->{PrintError} = 1;
>
> my $sql = "BEGIN  TRAN
>
>          INSERT INTO $table ...
>
>          UPDATE $table ....
>
>          COMMIT TRAN";
> $dbh->do($sql);
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using DBD::ODBC so bare this in mind when you read the following.

By default DBI will be in AutoCommit mode unless you disabled it.

Don't pass multiple pieces of SQL which uses transactions like this to SQL Server via the do method as DBD::ODBC will use SQLExecDirect for do by default and do is not really designed with multiple statements in mind. You are better using prepare/execute or splitting your SQL up and doing the commit in Perl like this:

```
$dbh->{RaiseError} = 1;
$dbh->begin_work;
eval {
  $dbh->do(q/insert.../);
  $dbh->do(q/update.../);
  $dbh->commit;
  1;
};
if ($@) {
  $dbh->rollback or warn "rollback failed";
}
```

or putting your insert/update in a SQL Server procedure.

Comment: Yes we use DBD::ODBC - so can we do a $dbh->{'AutoCommit'} = 0; ? since we have all the queries called from perl code using $dbh->do and we have all the queries inside a BEGIN TRAN and COMMIT TRAN block

Comment: You can try disabling AutoCommit but I'm not sure it is going to fix the entire problem. It just ins't a good idea to multiple sql statements in do.

Comment: Thanks bohica - Is there any other driver that i can use other than DBD::ODBC so that i could still have $dbh->do($sql) , where $sql has BEGIN TRAN followed by INSERT/UPDATE statements followed by END TRAN. If its a known issue with DBD::ODBC - then can any other library solve my problem and make the transaction still atomic without having to worry about setting AutoCommit and doing a commit everytime ?

Comment: Hi Bohica - I tried out with ->begin_work and it works perfectly. I also have $dbh->prepare() statements which have BEGIN TRAN followed by INSERT/UPDATE statements followed by END TRAN. Now if i do a $dbh->execute() of the prepared block , will it be atomic(even if constraint violations occur) or is it prone to issues like $dbh->do()